# Read Multiple Files StreamReader

Tags: c#, winforms

I have read and researched this throughout the internet and hoping now someone can help me through this. I am writing to read three different text files with different names, but I need to read through the text file name in order to determine which method I have to execute for that particular file. This is what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var readers = new List<StreamReader>();

foreach (var filename in names_of_files)
{
    if (do something?)
    {
        switch
    }
}

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
{
  (reads the file and does other stuff)
}
```

Below is the method that I am using to select multiple files.

```
private void LoadNewFile()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt) | *.txt";

    foreach (String file in ofd.FileNames)
    {
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            userSelectedFilePath += file;
            names_of_files.Add(userSelectedFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. If you need to do something different depending on file name then in your `foreach` you could do something like `if (filename == "first name") DoFirstThing() ; else if (filename == "second name") DoSecondThing();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the file names and process it differently based on the filename.

```
foreach (var filename in names_of_files)
{
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        if (filename.Contains(".txt"))
        {
            // Process text tile
            MyTextProcessingMethod(file);
        }
        else if (filename.Contains(".png"))
        {
            // Do something with the image
            MyImageProcessingMethod(file);
        }
        else if (filename.Contains("_specialCode")) {
            // Another file that has special processing based on its file name
            MySpecialProcessingMethod(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the file names are different everytime?

Comment: You explained in the question "I need to read through the text file name in order to determine which method I have to execute for that particular file."     What is it about the file name that allows you determine what to do with it?  And what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I have three different types of files with three different names(new file for everyday with date), I need to run through each file. I was able to use the contains but now getting "The given paths format is not supported".

Comment: Can you provide the name of the file when that error happens?